# Attenuation in the optical Bloch equations

Tags: quantum-mechanics, optics, density-operator

I'm currently dealing with the optical bloch equations (shown [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/121884/two-level-system-with-spontaneous-emission/121886#121886) in Emilio Pisanty's answer). I allready know that for a given density operator $\rho$, the coherent time evolution is given by the von Neumann equations:
$$
\frac{d}{dt} \hat{\rho} = \frac{i}{\hbar} [\hat{\rho}, \hat{H}]
$$
From those arrise the optical Bloch equations without attenuation. What I would like to know about is: How exactly is the phänomenon of spontaneous emission incorporated into this theory, to get the additional terms:

\begin{align}
\frac{d \rho_{gg}}{dt}_{sp} & = \gamma \rho_{ee},
\\
\frac{d \rho_{ee}}{dt}_{sp} & = -\gamma \rho_{ee},
\\
\frac{d \rho_{ge}}{dt}_{sp} & =-\frac\gamma2 \rho_{ge},
\\
\frac{d \rho_{eg}}{dt}_{sp} & =-\frac\gamma2 \rho_{eg}.
\end{align}

??

I denoted the terms with the subscript "sp", to indicate that this are not the only terms that contribute to the time derivative of the density matrix elements.

Are this additional terms somewhat phenomenologic? Like "We know there is something that brings states from state $|e⟩$ to state $|g⟩$ randomly, and destroys coherence, so let's model it this way? Or is there a model that explains why these terms look like that, and why the off-diagonal elements are only attenuated by half of the amount the diagonal elements are?

I tried to model it this way:
At time $t=0$, there are $I$ states $|\psi_i⟩$ with a propability of $p_i$. At time $t = dt$, some of those states will have spontaneously changed to the ground state, with a propability proportional to $dt$ and to a constant $\gamma$. That means at time $t = dt$, we have $I$ states $|\psi_i⟩$ with a propability $p_i - dt \gamma p_i$ and one state $| g ⟩$ with propability $\sum_i^I dt p_i \gamma = dt \gamma$.
This model yields the right terms for $\rho_{gg}$ and $\rho_{ee}$, but not for the off-diagonal terms:

The change in the density operator then is:
$$
d \hat{\rho} = \sum_i^I ( - dt p_i \gamma |\Psi_i ⟩⟨\Psi_i|) + dt \gamma |g⟩⟨g|  
$$
so
$$
d \rho_{gg} = ⟨g|\sum_i^I ( - dt p_i \gamma |\Psi_i ⟩⟨\Psi_i|) + dt \gamma |g⟩⟨g| \\
= \sum_i^I ( - dt \gamma p_i |⟨g|\Psi_i ⟩|^2) + dt \gamma ⟨g|g⟩⟨g|g⟩ \\
= \sum_i^I ( - dt \gamma p_i |⟨g|\Psi_i ⟩|^2) + dt \gamma \sum_i^I p_i ( |⟨g|\Psi_i ⟩|^2 + |⟨e|\Psi_i ⟩|^2) \\
= dt \gamma \sum_i^I p_i  |⟨e|\Psi_i ⟩|^2 \\
= dt \gamma ⟨e| \sum_i^I p_i |\Psi_i ⟩ ⟨\Psi_i|   |e⟩ = dt \gamma \rho_{ee}
$$

And that is the result that I want to obtain. Similar it works out for $\rho_{ee}$, but for the terms $\rho_{ge}$ and $\rho_{eg}$, the term is twice as big ( I don't get the factor 1/2 ). An additional thing that bothers me is that the spontaneous change of the system occurs with the same propability for each state $| \Psi_i ⟩$ I would expect the propability to be smaller if the state is nearer to be a ground state. 
Can somebody clearify wether my model is right or wrong, and how to model this right?I haven't found rigorous explanations for the optical bloch equations with attenuation, so I tried to come up with this.